# how to populate a list with sql queries

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an empty list `contacts = []`. I also have a sqlite3 database, with each row containing `first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, address` for a person. I want to populate my empty `contacts` list with a list `[first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, address]` for each individual/row in the database.

The way I am thinking to do it is doing

```
tempvar = cursor.fetchall()
rowcount = len(tempvar)
```

to get the number of rows in the database, to be used in a for loop as such:

```
for n in range(0, rowcount):
    contacts.append([a,
                     b,
                     c,
                     d,
                     e])
```

but I want a b c d and e to be queries for first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, and address of the `nth` person. Can someone help me fill in the blank? Hopefully I am making sense!

Comment: Have you tried printing the content of `tempvar`?

Comment: yeah, it returns an empty list. but I know I should have some rows of data in there. Why is that?

Comment: @owwix because your query is wrong, presumably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a database in sqlite3 with the columns, added 2 contacts and made the following code below:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('db/teste.db', check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()
contacts = c.execute("SELECT * FROM contacts").fetchall()

for x in range(len(contacts)):
    print(contacts[x])
```

The result of the code below:

```
('Gustavo', 'Araujo', 'guara@gmail.com', '556818293893', 'QELC04 BL B9')
('Fernando', 'Soares', 'fesoa@gmail.com', '559849892830', 'ASA SUL BSB')
```